# Sorting a 2D array according to coordinates and value

Tags: arrays, ruby, coordinates

I have an array that resembles this:

```
array = [["2","3","5","5"],["8","7","5","0"],["1","3","7","8"]]
```

The indices and subindices should resemble coordinates in an (y,x) format, i.e. the very first value "2" has the coordinates (0,0), and respectively the first "8" should have the coordinates (1,0). I am trying to input this into a new array that would have the coordinates followed by the value, i.e. first input to the new array would be 0,0,"2". How should I go about this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Could something like this be useful?

```
result = []
array.each_with_index do |subarray, x|
  subarray.each_with_index do |elem, y|
    result << [x, y, elem]
  end
end
irb(main):043:0> result
=> [[0, 0, "2"], [0, 1, "3"], [0, 2, "5"], [0, 3, "5"], [1, 0, "8"], [1, 1, "7"], [1, 2, "5"], [1, 3, "0"], [2, 0, "1"], [2, 1, "3"], [2, 2, "7"], [2, 3, "8"]]
```

Comment: I added an answer with a oneliner, if you are still curious.

Comment: Great! Awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

Oneliner, though:

```
array.map(&:each_with_index)
     .flat_map.with_index { |e, i| e.map { |e, j| [i, j, e] }  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of compact ways of doing that. I assume that, as in the example, the arrays that are the elements of `array` are all the same size.

**Convert to a matrix to use [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) methods**

```
require 'matrix'

Matrix[*array].each_with_index.map { |n,i,j| [i,j,n] }
  #=> [[0, 0, "2"], [0, 1, "3"], [0, 2, "5"], [0, 3, "5"],
  #    [1, 0, "8"], [1, 1, "7"], [1, 2, "5"], [1, 3, "0"],
  #    [2, 0, "1"], [2, 1, "3"], [2, 2, "7"], [2, 3, "8"]]
```

If the order of the offsets is not important, one can simplify to the following.

```
Matrix[*array].each_with_index.to_a
  #=> [["2", 0, 0], ["3", 0, 1], ["5", 0, 2], ["5", 0, 3],
  #    ["8", 1, 0], ["7", 1, 1], ["5", 1, 2], ["0", 1, 3],
  #    ["1", 2, 0], ["3", 2, 1], ["7", 2, 2], ["8", 2, 3]]
```

**Flatten and map using [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod)**

```
ncols = array.first.size
array.flatten.map.with_index { |n,i| [*i.divmod(ncols), n] }
  #=> [[0, 0, "2"], [0, 1, "3"], [0, 2, "5"], [0, 3, "5"],
  #    [1, 0, "8"], [1, 1, "7"], [1, 2, "5"], [1, 3, "0"],
  #    [2, 0, "1"], [2, 1, "3"], [2, 2, "7"], [2, 3, "8"]]
```